# groupadd: /var/lib/extrausers/group.xxxxx: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

So i installing XRDP. But, i get this message when configuring SSL Cert (`ssl-cert` package):

```bsh
root@localhost:~# apt-get install xrdp xorgxrdp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
.....
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.39) ...
ENTER EXTRAUSERS_GROUP_FILEEXIT EXTRAUSERS_GROUP_FILEENTER EXTRAUSERS_SHADOWGROUP_FILEEXIT EXTRAUSERS_SHADOWGROUP_FILEgroupadd: /var/lib/extrausers/group.27755: No such file or directory
groupadd: cannot lock /var/lib/extrausers/group; try again later.
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd --extrausers -g 114 ssl-cert' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package ssl-cert (--configure):
 installed ssl-cert package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
.....
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xrdp:
 xrdp depends on ssl-cert; however:
  Package ssl-cert is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
.....
Errors were encountered while processing:
 .....
 ssl-cert
 librdmacm1:armhf
 librados2
 xrdp
 ibverbs-providers:armhf
 librbd1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@localhost:~#
```

So please the help...

> System information:
>
> > Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> >
> > > Description   : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
> >
> > Release       : 18.04
>
> Codename      : bionic

Comment: Did you run either `apt-get -f install` or `dpkg --configure -a`? If neither of those work, try aptitude.

Comment: @Chev_603 but this is doesn't work for me